# Why does "Solve" not work for integral?

Tags: equation-solving, integral-equations

I have defined the following function:

```
f1[c_] := -Integrate[E^(-t), {t, 0, y}] - 
   Integrate[E^((-c)*t), {t, y, -Log[1/2]}]
```

When I solve this for c=1, I get f1(1)=-0.5.

However,

```
Solve[f1[y] == -0.5, y]
```

returns no solution. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works, using `Reals`

```
Solve[f1[y] == -1/2, y, Reals]//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. better to use exact numbers with `Solve`. so `1/2` instead of `0.5`.

see help on `Solve`